# How to install Apache Bench on Windows 7?

Tags: apache, apachebench

I want to install Apache Bench on Windows, can someone tell me which MSI to get?

I did install some MSI but it seems to have installed apache http server.

I just need to run Apache Bench, as I am testing an IIS asp.net application.

Comment: seems like a question for server fault

Comment: The bounty prevents it from being closed and transferred to Server Fault.

Comment: Is there anything else you need to know to award the bounty?

Answer (score 165, accepted):

It sounds like you don't want to install Apache, but you do want [Apache Bench](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/programs/ab.html).  May I recommend [XAMPP](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp-windows.html#641)? Download the zip or 7zip versions (much larger download than regular Apache but you won't have to install).  Unzip the download.

This is where what I would recommend, and where you currently are converge.  Since you already have Apache installed you should already have Apache Bench.

You will find it under

```
.\apache\bin\ab.exe
```

in the zip file, if that is what you downloaded, it will be under

```
.\xampp\apache\bin\ab.exe
```

Comment: I don't have apache already installed, I just want to run ab w/o having to install apache, is this possible?  I'm not using apache web server.

Comment: @Blankman would you be kind enough to take a look at [the faq](http://stackoverflow.com/faq)

Comment: If you want to use it without the rest of XAMPP, you need to copy the whole `.\apache\bin` directory, since `ab.exe` relies on the `.dll` files there.

Comment: The XAMPP page no longer has the zip or 7zip versions available for download.

Comment: @ANeves they still have if you click "More downloads" you end up at their sourceforge which has still .zip/.7z

https://sourceforge.net/projects/xampp/files/XAMPP%20Windows/

Comment: Git Bash, Windows 7: `$ ./ab.exe -c 10 -n 100 'https://www.google.com/'` -> 
`SSL not compiled in; no https support`.

Answer (score 24):

You can download the Apache server zip files
(a lot smaller in size compared to AMPP packages) from the following site

[Apache Haus Downloads](http://apachehaus.com/cgi-bin/download.plx)

and unzip it. Find the bin folder; you will find `ab.exe` there.

Comment: Git Bash, Windows 7: `$ ./ab.exe -c 10 -n 100 'https://www.google.com/'` -> 
`SSL not compiled in; no https support`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7402502/4293444

Answer (score 4):

Here's some documentation on [Using Apache HTTP Server on Microsoft Windows](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/platform/windows.html).

The [Apache Bench](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/programs/ab.html) is often called and refered to as `ab`.

Your Windows installation of `Apache` should contain a `ab.exe` and `abs.exe` file.

That'd be what you're looking for.

Comment: I believe there is a way to install ab w/o having to install apache no?

Comment: well, I'm no expert on Apache Bench, but it probably depends on many stuff that comes with Apache's installation. It's probably possible to get Apache Bench working without installing the Apache executable, but you'd still need many things from that installation to get it up and working. I don't see it in its own bundle/package and that's probably no accident.

Answer (score 2):

ab is an independent file, runs without apache http. so install apache http, copy ab from bin folder and uninstall http server.