# Quick and dirty performance testing of web services - what are my options?

Tags: c#, performance, testing, performance-testing

I have some simple web services, retrieving information from a database and storing info in a database, written in C#, using IIS. My boss has asked that my boss I compile a very quick report on the performance of these web services for tomorrow. As an intern with no experience of this, I am wondering what are my options here ? I have roughly 2 hours to spend testing this.

What I have done :

- Created 2 simple web tests with simple use case flows.
- Created a load test using a step-load pattern which shows when the
  application breaks (how many concurrent users results in errors/queries not being returned).

What other important metrics are their to report on ? What are my other options for testing performance here that would be quick, dirty, and most effective ?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simplest Load testing with options on concurrent requests/threads - I use [Apache Bench](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/programs/ab.html).

[Here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/programs/ab.html#output) is a list of output that Bench gives you, maybe some of these metrics help your case.

Answer (score 0):

A couple places to check are [ApacheBench](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/programs/ab.html) which can tell you how many requests/sec you can handle in addition to other metrics.

Also available is the [Microsoft Web Capacity Analysis Tool](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/231282)

Comment: Is this appropriate to use with IIS ?

Comment: It should work, following the suggestion from [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7327099/how-to-install-apache-bench-on-windows-7)